# Issue with output from loop

Tags: java

I'm creating a class that rolls three die 5000 times, and counts the number of times all three die roll a 1. I have the loop correct as the output continues to show around the percentage as to how many times this condition is met, but it ends up printing EVERY iteration of all 5000 rolls in the output

(ex. The number of times the three die rolled a three were 3times.
The number of times the three die rolled a three were 3times.
The number of times the three die rolled a three were 3times.
The number of times the three die rolled a three were 4times.)

I just want the end number. I tried using break which messed up the calculation, and also creating a new variable (result) and instantiating it to the value of the counter but that didn't work either. Here is the main method where the issue is.

```
public class PairOfDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


           PairOfDiceTwo die1, die2, die3;
           int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, counter1, b, result;


           die1 = new PairOfDiceTwo();
           die2 = new PairOfDiceTwo();
           die3 = new PairOfDiceTwo();

           counter1 = 0;
           for (int c = 0; c < 5000; c++)
           {
               die1.roll();
               die2.roll();
               die3.roll();

               sum1 = die1.getFaceValue();
               sum2 = die2.getFaceValue();
               sum3 = die3.getFaceValue();

               if (sum1 == 1 && sum2 == 1 && sum3 == 1)
               {
                   counter1++;
               }

               result = counter1;


               System.out.println("The number of times the three die rolled a"
                       + " three were " +result+ "times.");
```

and the other class if it's necessary

```
public class PairOfDiceTwo {
    private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public PairOfDiceTwo()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value mutator.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void setFaceValue (int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value accessor.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Move the print statement out of your for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a new variable. This is because your `System.out.println();` is inside the for loop. Just move it outside and it will only print after the loop has finished executing.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't catch that.